# Determine which of a set of images has been recompressed/resaved the least

Tags: image, image-processing

I'm working on a system that does fuzzy image deduplication.

Right now, I have a [functional system](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator) that can do large-scale [phash](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html) fuzzy image searching and deduplication via either DCT-based or gradient-based perceptual hashes.

However, while determining if an image has been reduced in size is programatically trivial, how can I determine which image is the parent of which?

Basically, if I have two images with the same resolution, where one is a resaved version of the other (either in a different format (jpg/png), or simply recompressed), how can I determine which one is the original in a reliable manner?

(Note: Assume all metadata has been stripped from the images, I wish it were that simple.)

Bonus points if any solution is fairly easy to implement in python.

Comment: The resaved image will have more noise, can you measure that?

Comment: @sashoalm - I thought about that, but then JPEG compression can introduce quantization artifacts, so I'm not sure how viable it would be?

Comment: Check the size in bytes? :-)

Comment: @jcl - that assumes the resave is in a more efficient format.

Comment: I was kidding of course. I have no clue... if I am to say something in the wild I'd do some kind of b/w edge detection algorithm with some tolerance (or maybe after denoising) and check for the amount of "white parts"... but that's without much thought

Comment: @FakeName A slightly dumber approach, but nonetheless it might work - there are not that many JPEG conversion libraries, and IF the compression is deterministic, you might try to compress image A and see if it becomes image B. Try this with the most popular libraries, and who knows, you might catch 90% of the cases. Also, for PNGs - they're not lossy anyway, and I doubt someone would first convert to a lossy format, and then to a PNG, it won't make sense. In practice, it's just JPEG 99% of the you'll be dealing with.

Comment: And another thought - create a difference image from 2 images after recompression, and see if there are any discernible patterns. You might find something. That is, if you have A, and you resave it as B, create C, where each pixel(C)=pixel(A)-pixel(B). What do those images look?

Comment: @sashoalm - I'm dealing with content sourced from the web, so I really cannot make *any* assumptions about the compression engine. Also, yes, people do convert from jpeg to png to jpeg, and the inverse, for no sane reason I can determine.

Comment: @FakeName That's why I said it might work in 90% of the cases, not 100%. Anyway, did you try the other idea - try researching on the pixel-by-pixel difference.

Comment: No specific answer, but I would consider looking at measuring the entropy of the images and seeing how that varies with re-saves - see my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807303/how-can-i-automatically-determine-whether-an-image-file-depicts-a-photo-or-a-gr/26807785#26807785 and also have a read of this article http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I linked that *exact* hackerfactor article in my question (reading ahoy!). I actually am building on top of a fairly extensive phash image search system that can use both DCT-based phashes and gradient-based phashes. I'm seeking to be able to determine which of two images that are already phash-matches is the less-degraded version, so I can delete the poorer-quality one, and modify it's references to point to the higher quality version as part of a larger data-deduplication system.

Comment: My primary concern with entropy measurement is that aggressive JPEG compression can *introduce* entropy, as quantization noise. Really, I was hoping someone had written a paper or something on the topic, and I was just failing to find it in my googling.

Comment: Realistically, I think I'm going to have to put together a set of tests to evaluate various approaches, but I was hoping to avoid that. It's not *hard* (I know `PIL` and `numpy` fairly well), but it is a lot of work.

Comment: Thinking about it, I can probably normalize image entropy into a entropy/pixel ratio, which should be fairly simple to search within a database. Hmmm, I need to do some testing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I evaluated using image entropy to compare images. It's not useful. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a positive answer, but I spent a while of time evaluating the use of average entropy per-pixel to determine if it could be a useful metric for determining how compressed an image is.

I have a [write up here](https://github.com/fake-name/ImProcessing-Scratchpad/tree/master/entropyCode).

Some excerpts:

Variance in entropy across compression levels on [SIPI reference image database](http://sipi.usc.edu/database/) images.

[image]
<sup>In retrospect, the x-axis should be labeled "JPEG *Quality* level". Higher numbers mean better quality</sup>

While per-pixel entropy does decline sharply at extremely aggressive compression levels, it does not vary in a way that correlates well with compression level.

This means that any attempt to compare two images by inspecting the entropy will likely have issues unless one knows *exactly* what compression level the image had been resaved at.